# FocusListener not working on Mac

Tags: java, macos, swt

I have the following code:

```
        Display display = new Display();
        Shell shell = new Shell(display);
        shell.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, true));
        shell.setText("One Potato, Two Potato");

        // Create the focus listener
        FocusListener listener = new FocusListener() {
            public void focusGained(FocusEvent event) {
                Button button = (Button) event.getSource();
                button.setText("I'm It!");
            }

            public void focusLost(FocusEvent event) {
                Button button = (Button) event.getSource();
                button.setText("Pick Me!");
            }
        };
        // Create the buttons and add the listener to each one
        for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
            Button button = new Button(shell, SWT.PUSH);
            button.setLayoutData(new GridData(GridData.FILL_HORIZONTAL));
            button.setText("Pick Me!");
            button.addFocusListener(listener);
        }
        // Display the window
        shell.pack();
        shell.open();
        while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
            if (!display.readAndDispatch()) {
                display.sleep();
            }
        }
```

But it doesn't seem to work. I am working on Eclipse IDE on Mac machine. Is there something wrong in what I am doing?

Answer (score 1):

This might not be the answer you were looking for, but i too noticed some listeners do not work on mac(the focus listener doesn't work on shell either and other listeners are buggy too on mac). Your best bet here would be to try and replace Button with Text. And make it look similar. The focus listener works on Text even on mac. So, your code would look like this:

```
 Display display = new Display();
    Shell shell = new Shell(display);
    shell.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, true));
    shell.setText("One Potato, Two Potato");

    // Create the focus listener
    FocusListener listener = new FocusListener() {
        public void focusGained(FocusEvent event) {
            Text text = (Text) event.getSource();
            text.setText("I'm It!");
        }

        public void focusLost(FocusEvent event) {
            Text text = (Text) event.getSource();
            text.setText("Pick Me!");
        }
    };
    // Create the buttons and add the listener to each one
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        Text text = new Text(shell, SWT.PUSH);
        text.setLayoutData(new GridData(GridData.FILL_HORIZONTAL));
        text.setText("Pick Me!");
        text.addFocusListener(listener);
    }
    // Display the window
    shell.pack();
    shell.open();
    while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
        if (!display.readAndDispatch()) {
            display.sleep();
        }
    }
```

Now the only thing you have to do is change the field so it will look more like a button. Hope it helps. 
Best of luck!

P.S.: Someone should open a bug regarding this issue.